# Lagrange multipliers in global consensus optimization

Tags: convex-optimization

Consider the following convex optimization problem:
$$\text{minimize} ~ \sum_{i=1}^N f_i(x) ~ \text{ s.t. } ~ x \in X,$$
where $X$ is an $m$-dimensional convex set, and $f_i$'s are convex.
We can rewrite this as:
$$\text{minimize} ~ \sum_{i=1}^N f_i(x_i) ~ \text{ s.t. } ~ x_i \in X ~ \text{ and } ~ x_i = z ~\forall i.$$
This is called the global consensus problem (refer to Chapter 7 of [Distributed Optimization and Statistical Learning via the Alternating Direction Method of Multipliers](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/pdf/admm_distr_stats.pdf)).
The partial augmented Lagrangian for this problem is:
$$L_\rho(x, z, y) = \sum_{i=1}^N\left( f_i(x_i) + y_i^T (x_i - z) + \rho/2 \Vert x_i - z \Vert_2^2 \right).$$
Let $(x^*, z^*, y^*)$ be the optimal solution. We know that $x_i^* = z^*$ for all $i$.
Here are my questions:

- Do we have $y_i^* = 0_m$?
- If not, can we show that $\sum_i y_i^* = 0_m$? Also, what can we say about $\Vert y_i^* \Vert_2$ if $X = \{ x \in [0, 1]^m : \Vert x \Vert_1 \le 1\}$?

Comment: It is not at all clear why you would expect the multipliers to sum to zero? Also, the $X$ at the end is not convex.

Comment: On page 50 of the book, it is shown that with ADMM updates, $\sum_i y_i^k = 0$. And we know that $y_i^k \to y_i^*$. I've changed the $X$. I think it's convex now.